# Why are files suddenly disappear after downloaded on Unihertz Jelly Star?

Tags: downloading, unihertz

I tried to use Videoder to download some music, but they immediately disappeared as soon as the download was finished. I'm on a Unihertz Jelly Star, and I tried downloading the files to many different folders, but the files always disappear.

If I move the files to the safe folder (the folder where only I can delete something and my phone has no say) while the files are downloading, they stay, but only how much was downloaded at that point, and when I move them back out, they stay.

Comment: Please add more details about your phone (model and Android version) as well as the app you use for download and the one you use for seeing the files (for both apps please add link to store).