# Android Accessibility Suite Doesn't Remember App Settings

Tags: accessibility, android-13, auto-rotation, unihertz

Okay so, I have a Unihertz Jelly Star running Android 13.
Because it has such a small screen, I'd like the ability to quickly toggle auto rotation. If I could add it as one of the functions on the reprogrammable shortcut button that would be ideal, but I can't find a way to easily do that. So I went with the next best thing I could find.

I installed Button Remapper from the play store. This works well enough. I can set it to toggle rotation with a double tap of one of the volume buttons or a tap-and-hold of the app switcher button, easy peasy. There's just one little caveat. Android Accessibility Suite doesn't remember the settings. If the phone is sitting idle, or I'm on it and haven't used the toggle for a little bit, the Accessibility Suite settings to enable Button Remapper to make changes switches itself off.

I've switched both Button Remapper and Android Accessibility Suite to 'Unrestricted' under battery usage. Button Remapper initially had 'Pause App Activity if Unused' enabled by default, so I switched that off. It has made no difference whatsoever. Currently I have the accessibility shortcut to enable it by holding both volume buttons, so when it disables itself, I can quickly turn it back on again. But at that point I might as well just use the auto rotation toggle in the notification pull shade. I just want a quick, easy ***hardware*** (nothing obstructing the screen) toggle I can use from anywhere that I can just set and forget.

Is there something I'm overlooking here? Or am I just SOL & just need to bite the bullet and go back to using the damn notification pullshade toggle?
Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated <3

Comment: Seeing there's another issue of [files suddenly disappear after being downloaded on Unihertz Jelly Star?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/253670/44325), I'm afraid they implemented something on the OS/system-level that reverted many things...